# android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table user has no column named friends

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I'm getting error when I try to insert a new row into SQLite. I've searched for any error in my code, but I can't find any error. Any help would be great!

Here is my error:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table user has no column named friends (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO user(email,name,api_key,friends,register_date) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)
```

Here is my database:

```
private static final String TABLE_USER = "user";
private static final String COLUMN_ID = "id";
private static final String COLUMN_NAME = "name";
private static final String COLUMN_EMAIL = "email";
private static final String COLUMN_API_KEY = "api_key";
private static final String COLUMN_FRIENDS = "friends";
private static final String COLUMN_REGISTER_DATE = "register_date";

public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String SQL_CREATE_LOGIN = String.format(
            "CREATE TABLE %s (%s, %s, %s, %s)",
            TABLE_USER,
            String.format("%s integer primary key autoincrement", COLUMN_ID),
            String.format("%s varchar(30)", COLUMN_NAME),
            String.format("%s varchar(40)", COLUMN_EMAIL),
            String.format("%s varchar(32)", COLUMN_API_KEY),
            String.format("%s integer", COLUMN_FRIENDS),
            String.format("%s text", COLUMN_REGISTER_DATE)
    );
    db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_LOGIN);
);
```

And this is my insert code:

```
public void addUser(String name, String email, String api_key, int friends, String register_date) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(COLUMN_NAME, name); // Name
    values.put(COLUMN_EMAIL, email); // Email
    values.put(COLUMN_API_KEY, api_key); // Email
    values.put(COLUMN_FRIENDS, friends); // Friends
    values.put(COLUMN_REGISTER_DATE, register_date); // Created At

    // Inserting Row
    long id = db.insert(TABLE_USER, null, values);
    db.close(); // Closing database connection

    Log.d(TAG, "New user inserted into sqlite: " + id);
}
```

Comment: what is db version .?

Comment: Uninstall previous and install fresh one then its work

Comment: @SuryaPrakashKushawah thanks for your answer. It's version 2. I've tried it but it didn't solve my problem

Comment: add on upgrade code here

Comment: how to insert code in here? lol

Comment: public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        String SQL_DELETE_LOGIN = String.format(
                "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS %s",
                TABLE_USER
        );
        // Drop older table if existed
        db.execSQL(SQL_DELETE_LOGIN);

        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);
    }

Comment: @ArthurBachtiar see my answer

Comment: You only created 4 columns in your CREATE statement

Comment: Also, please find the edit link on your question if you wanted to change or add code. Don't use the comments

Comment: Thanks for all your answer, it doesn't show any error. I've uninstalled and installed my app again, and it solve the problem. Thank you :D

Comment: If this app is in use by users they will probably get a crash when they get the update.  If that's the case you need to provide an update script and increment the database version.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String SQL_CREATE_LOGIN = String.format(
            "CREATE TABLE %s (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",
            TABLE_USER,
            String.format("%s integer primary key autoincrement", COLUMN_ID),
            String.format("%s varchar(30)", COLUMN_NAME),
            String.format("%s varchar(40)", COLUMN_EMAIL),
            String.format("%s varchar(32)", COLUMN_API_KEY),
            String.format("%s integer", COLUMN_FRIENDS),
            String.format("%s text", COLUMN_REGISTER_DATE)
    );
    db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_LOGIN);
);
```

Maybe you forgot to edit your `CREATE TABLE %s (%s, %s, %s, %s)` to `CREATE TABLE %s (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)`. The table that you want to create has 6 columns.

Comment: Aw, thanks @Randyka Yudhistira .  Let me try it first, thanks btw

Comment: I still got the error :(

Comment: Thanks, it doesn't error anymore. I've uninstalled it and install again, then boom, the error doesn't show up anymore. Thank you :D

Comment: @ArthurBachtiar you're welcome. please accept my answer then.